# Excel Office 365 Connection String on Text File

Tags: excel, vba, office365

Just wanted to ask in regards to connection strings on Excel VBA Office 365.

I was using the below connection string to connect on a txt file using Excel 2016.

```
ConnCSV.Open "Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" & path & ";Extensions=a,asxc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=NO;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Upon testing on Excel Office 365 I got the below error

```
"ODBC Driver Manager Data source name not found"
```

I've tried to use the below string connection and also have MS Access Engine of all versions installed, to no avail.

```
ConnCSV.Open "Driver={Microsoft Access Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};Dbq=" & path & ";Extensions=a,asxc,csv,tab,txt;HDR=NO;Persist Security Info=False"
```

Is there any new connection string needed to be used specifically for Excel Office 365?

Greatly appreciate it in advance.

Thanks